# How to get text from multiple edittext in android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

In my application, I am creating multiple editTexts dynamically on a button click like this:

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                 EditText et= new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                 et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                 ll.addView(et);// ll is Linear Layout.
            }
```

Now I want to get text from all the edittexts that are created on Button click in a single String. I am not getting any idea how to do this. Somebody please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should help you:

```
    String assembledString = "";
    View tempView;
    for(int i = 0; i < ll.getChildCount(); i++){
        tempView = ll.getChildAt(i);
        if(tempView instanceof EditText){
            assembledString += ((EditText) tempView).getText().toString();
        }
    }
```

Basically assuming ll is a layout of some type (Frame, Linear, Relative) you can do getChildCount(). This allows you to loop through all children. Then its just a case of getting the view and checking its an EditText. If so then you can grab the string and do whatever you want with it.

Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Use a container in the parent class:

```
List<EditText> edits = new ArrayList<EditText>();
...
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
   EditText et= new EditText(MainActivity.this);
   et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
   ll.addView(et);// ll is Linear Layout.
   edits.add(et);
}
```

Then iterate that list to get the text.

Comment: This is a better answer than the [accepted one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27232653) as this answer does **not** make the assumption that we want to grab all the children edit text views. We might not want to do that, if we have some special (e.g. header) views that we want to skip and handle separately.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the childs of 'LinearLayout' and get their text to do what ever you want

```
 String text = "";

for(int i =0;i<ll.getChildCount();i++)
{
  try
    {
         text += ((EditText)ll.getChildAt(i)).gettext().toString();
     }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
  }

}
```

This will work for sure..